# Display only categories until click/mouseover

Tags: magento, categories

I'm having a problem with the different categories in a Magento menu bar.  Right now they just display as a list of all categories and sub categories.  I just want to see the categories and have the sub-categories appear upon click or mouseover of the category.

The site in question is [www.babydiscountshop.nl](http://www.babydiscountshop.nl)

I'm from the Netherlands and don't speak very good English, so please keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you were making modifications to your theme. There are two things you need to do:

1. Ensure that you have a good category tree (categories having subcategories) and that every category and subcategory you want to see (no matter if you need to see them always or on hover or on mouse click) are visible in the menu (options Is Active and Include in the Navigation Menu should be enabled for those categories)
2. Modify the CSS of your theme so only the top level categories are visible right away and the rest is visible on hover
3. Add some JavaScript that enables you to show categories on click

The second point requires the following CSS rules:

1. Second (and every deeper) level categories should be hidden (`#nav ol ul {display: none}`)
2. They should become visible on hover (e.g. `#nav ol ul:hover {display: block}`)

In the third point, you should do the following things:

1. For every category that has child categories, you should prevent default onclick action (this would go to a given category) and instead, show its child categories (child unordered list is a sibling of the `a` html element you click (change its default  `display: none` to `display: block` or something). Remember to do it only for `a` elements that actually have `ul` sibling.
2. Second click on the same `a` node should hide its sibling `ul`

Refer to the default Magento rwd theme files (`app/design/frontend/rwd/default`) if you're unsure how to proceed.